# Make cube spin in Ludo game-Javascript

Tags: javascript

Greetings fellow programmers.I've created a cube with six different divs for Ludo game.Divs contain black dots and every dot is for specific number(one dot for number on, two for two).I've put them all together in one div.My question is how i can change dots in different order with Math.floor(Math.random()*6) until
i get six and start a game ? Here are the codes i have tryed:

```
      <div id='dice'>

      <div class='dice'>

      <div class='dice1' id='b'></div>

      </div>

      </div>

      <div id='dice0'>

      <div class='dice2'>

      <div class='dice3' id='c'></div>
      <div class='dice4' id='c'></div>

      </div>

      </div>

      <div id='dice1'>


      <div class='dice5'>


      <div class='dice6' id='d'></div>
      <div class='dice7' id='d'></div>
      <div class='dice8' id='d'></div>

      </div>

      </div>

      <div id='dice2'>

      <div class='dice9'>

      <div class='dice10' id='e'></div>
      <div class='dice11' id='e'></div>
      <div class='dice12' id='e'></div>
      <div class='dice13' id='e'></div>

      </div>

      </div>

      <div id='dice3'>

      <div class='dice14'>

      <div class='dice15' id='f'></div>
      <div class='dice16' id='f'></div>
      <div class='dice17' id='f'></div>
      <div class='dice18' id='f'></div>
      <div class='dice19' id='f'></div>

      </div>

      </div>

      <div id='dice4'>

      <div class='dice20'>

      <div class='dice21' id='g'></div>
      <div class='dice22' id='g'></div>
      <div class='dice23' id='g'></div>
      <div class='dice24' id='g'></div>
      <div class='dice25' id='g'></div>
      <div class='dice26' id='g'></div>

      </div>

      </div>

      </div>


     var dice1=document.querySelector('#dice');
     var dice2=document.querySelector('#dice0');
     var dice3=document.querySelector('#dice1');
     var dice4=document.querySelector('#dice2');
     var dice5=document.querySelector('#dice3');
     var dice6=document.querySelector('#dice4');
     var d2=document.querySelector('.d1');

     var cube=[1,2,3,4,5,6];

     function rolling()  {

     for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {

     d2.innerHTML=cube[Math.floor(Math.random()*6)];

     }

     }
```

Comment: Using duplicate IDs is invalid in HTML.

Comment: So what should i do to make them change their order ?